# how to deploy IE web control along with application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i am using ie web control in my application,now i want to deploy ie control along with my application as my client doesn't install ie or have lower version that i am using. how is it possible? There is an application Stylizer at http://www.stylizerapp.com/ which is using multiple web browsers as well as multiple versions of same browser.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a .Net web browser control - it will use the version of an Internet Explorer, that is currently installed. If your user has the wrong version of IE then you desire him to be using - check versions from code and advise to upgrade before using.

If there was a way to deliver IE8 functionality without going through a heavyweight install there currently is - would MS be bothering with it?

I remember times when people tried to remove IE from windows for the sake of performance - but it was more of a hack, so I doubt you are to find Windows deployments with .net but without IE.

Answer (score 0):

The "IE Web Control" *is* Internet Explorer. There is no way to use a different version from the version installed on the computer.